# Wrong revert in git

Tags: git

I wanted to revert the last push on branch `branch1` and I used this command when I was on `branch1`:

```
git push -f origin HEAD^:master
```

and instead of writing `git push -f origin HEAD^:branch1`. The result is that my master become `branch1`. Now I want to bring back my old `master`. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes your local `master` branch was upto date with `origin/master`.

Yes, you can force push local master on the remote master again:

```
git push -f origin master:master
```

You don't need to be explicit on to what you are pushing here, because git will assume same name branches, so you can shorten it to:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: This is wrong if the local master does not equal origin/master~1

Comment: my understanding is that he pushed accidentally to master rather than ``branch1``, and wants to restore master

Comment: @chelmertz and yes, my answer assumes that his local master was upto date before overwriting the remote master (I see what you mean now)

Comment: +1 to your last comment, if you add that to your answer, you get +1 there too :) Otherwise: can you provide an answer that takes care of the other scenario, i.e. when his master is not in sync with origin/master but still wants to revert his wrong push?

Comment: I have used `git push -f origin SHA1_to_old_master:master`